# Cannot find the solution to 400 bad Axios request involving JWT Token and Authentication in React JS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, jwt, formik

I'm trying to implement authentication with JWT token into my React App. I'm having a hard time solving why I get a 400 Bad Request every time I send an axios post request to sign up as a new user to update my user collections in Monogo DB. The strange thing is that even tho I get a 400 Bad Request from axios, my users collection updates regardless.

The URL that the post request sends is correct and the endpoints are defined correctly.

How can I fix this?

Here is my front end app.js code :

```
function App() {
const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(false);

const login = useCallback((uid, token)=> {
setToken(true);
setUserId(uid)
},[]);

const logout = useCallback(()=> {
setToken(null);
setUserId(null);
},[]);

let routes;

if(token) {
routes = (

        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage >} />
        <Route path="/product-detail" element={<ProductDetailPage />} />
        <Route path="/sub-category" element={<SubCategory />} />
        <Route path="/saved" element={<SavedPage />} />
        <Route path="/inbox" element={<InboxPage />} />
        <Route path="/deals" element={<DealsPage />} />
      </Routes>
       
    
    )

} else {
routes = (

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/product-detail" element={<ProductDetailPage />} />
        <Route path="/sub-category" element={<SubCategory />} />
      </Routes>
     
    )

}

return (
<AuthContext.Provider value={{
isLoggedIn: !!token,
token: token,
userId : userId,
login : login,
logout: logout } }>

    <BrowserRouter>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      {routes}
    </ChakraProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContext.Provider>

);
}

export default App;
```

Here is my signUp Formik form :

```
const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

const signUpFormik = useFormik({
initialValues : {
firstName : "",
lastName : "",
location : "",
email : "",
password : "",
},
onSubmit : async (values) => {
try {
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3005/user/signup", values, {
headers: {
"Authorization" : "Bearer " + auth.token,
},
});
auth.login(res.data.userId, res.data.token)
console.log(res.data);
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
console.log(error.response);
}
}});
```

Here is my AuthContext file that attempts to manage state in react. :

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
isLoggedIn: false,
userId: null,
token : null,
login : () => {},
logout : () => {}
});
```

For the back end rest api, here is the check-auth.js :

```
import HttpError from "../models/http-error.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const checkAuth = (req,res,next) => {

    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        if (!token) {
            throw new Error('Authentication failed!');
        }
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'supersecretkey');
        req.userData = { userId : decodedToken.userId }
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Authentication failed', 401);
        return (error); 
    }

}
```

here is my signup controller function :

```
export const userSignUp = async (req, res) => {

    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password,
      location,
    } = req.body;
    
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
    
    const user = new User({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password : passwordHash,
      location,
    });
    
    try {
      let token;
      token = jwt.sign({userId : user.id, email : user.email }, 
      'supersecretkey', 
      { expiresIn : '1h', }
      );
    
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.response)
    }
    
    try {
      const savedUser = await user.save();
      res.status(200).json(savedUser, token);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: "Error creating user",
        error,
      });
    }

};
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `console.log(error.response)`, try `console.error(error.response?.data)`. What does it say? Also, have you added the required JSON body-parsing middleware, eg `app.use(express.json())`?

Comment: Hi @Phil , yes I have app.use(express.json()), and when i do console.error(error.response?.data), I get an error saying, LoginSignUpForm.jsx:35 
{message: 'Error creating user', error: {…}}
error
: 
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Error creating user"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: You need to expand out that `error` property. I'd also strongly advise adding `console.error(error)` to your server-side `catch` block before sending the response

Comment: Thx for tip, it's helped me delve deeper in the server side. so this the error i get before sending the response :
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: { ... values for user signing up}

Comment: @Phil, I asked ChatGPT and it solved it. It told me that I should only send a status response in my controller function instead of savedUser and Token.
I changed it to this :
 try {
    await user.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Signing up failed, please try again later." });
    return;
  } res.status(201).json({ message: "User created successfully." });